# What is the Royal Bonus DLC?

Tags: small-world-2

Humble Bundle's PC and Android 11 included Small World 2 and its Royal Bonus DLC. This DLC does not appear to be available for purchase anywhere, although it was also included for backers of the [Small World 2 Kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/daysofwonder/small-world-2-the-return/description). The Kickstarter seems to indicate that the Royal Bonus is a physical (cardboard) reward, but that doesn't make sense if it's DLC.

What is the Royal Bonus?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer on [the developer's website](http://www.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/expansions/#royal-bonus):

> A mini-expansion funded with Kickstarter
>
> Contains
>
> - 3 new Race banners and tokens (Fauns, Igors & Shrubmen)
> - 3 new Special Power badges (Fireball, Aquatic & Behemoth)

And it looks like the cardboard reward referenced in the Kickstarter project was a Kickstarter exclusive reward that featured the races and powers from this DLC.